# vue.js: `vue create` creates only 3 files in project folder (package.json, package-lock.json, README.md)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, installation, environment

After installing vue (`npm install -g @vue/cli`) and then creating a new project with:

```
vue create projectname
```

Only 3 files are created in the project folder:

- package.json
- package-lock.json
- README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an environment issue. Switching to `development environment` solves it. Type the following into your command line.

1.) Check which value your `NODE_ENV` variable is set to:

```
echo $NODE_ENV
```

2.) If the output is `production`, then set it to `development`:

```
export NODE_ENV=development
```